# Inserting Google+ community into iframe of webpage

Tags: iframe, blogs, google-plus

I want to be able to insert my Google+ community into my blog, but the usual is not working

`<iframe src="https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/105097572656694316399"></iframe>`

It just displays and empty box with no DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google+ blocks this from being possible through the following:

```
'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

This is done to preserve the stream experience for Google+. For now, you should just link to the community instead of trying to embed it.

You can request that this feature be supported by adding or staring a feature to [the Google+ platform issue tracker.](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/)

Comment: I can't speak to the original poster's reason for doing this, but it is common to want to show a small portion of a stream (a profile or community's posts) on a website in order to convince them to follow the person/community on Google+. There are Twitter badges that do this, for example.

Comment: Makes sense, updating with link to the issue tracker.